# Speed up counting the number of A[i] * A[j] * A[k] = A[l] where i < j < k < l

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, memoization

I recently got onto the following problem: we consider the following array:

```
A = [2, 3, 6, 1, 6, 4, 12, 24]
```

we need to count the number of times these two conditions are satisfied within the array:

```
A[i] * A[j] * A[k] = A[l] so that 0 <= i < j < k < l < len(A)
```

for this example the result should be 8. example of satisfied conditions within the array:

```
2 * 3 * 1 = 6
2 * 6 * 1 = 12
6 * 1 * 4 = 24
3 * 1 * 4 = 12
```

The straightforward solution I created using python:

```
A = [2, 3, 6, 1, 6, 4, 12, 24]
result = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(A)):
        for k in range(j + 1, len(A)):
            for l in range(k + 1, len(A)):
                if A[i] * A[j] * A[k] == A[l]:
                    result += 1
print(result)
```

I need to find a way to speed up the program using dynamic, maybe memoization or pre computing.

```
result = 0
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(i + 1, A):
        for k in range(j + 1, A):
             #TODO
print(result)
```

I was thinking of creating a dictionary that contains a set of dictionaries for each number, to indicate the number and its position, example:

```
speed_up = {
    6: {
        2: True
        4: True
    }, 
    1: {
       3: True
    },
    ...
}
```

then we check like the following:

```
result = 0
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(i + 1, A):
        for k in range(j + 1, A):
            x = A[i] * A[j] * A[k]
            if x in speed_up:
                result += len([z[0] for z in speed_up[x].items() if z[0] > k])
```

This way we will count all occurrences of the same number after the index k at once, we will not have to go through all array.

Please let me know if my optimisation is flawed, and if there's better optimisation using dynamic programming techniques such as memoization or pre computing.

Comment: (One unrelated idea is ordering the values (numbers? naturals? "real"?) (keeping track of their original position). Values of $0$ and $(±)1$ are special.)

Comment: This can be done in $O(n^2)$ time, assuming $O(1)$-time lookup for some hashmap.

Comment: @JohnL.: can you substantiate ?

Comment: In the worst case, when all elements are $1$, all $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ quadruples fulfill the condition (you can find less trivial examples). Using the counting trick of @plshelp, you can reduce to $O(n^3)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes.  However, the OP is gone.  Instead of "lookup", I should have written "operations".

Comment: @JohnL.: as I understand the policy, these questions/answers are for everyone in the community.

Comment: @JohnL.: my bet is that your $O(n^2)$ solution is wrong, due to equal values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If you ask a question, I will answer. It is fine if all elements are 1.

Comment: @JohnL.: this is not the case I have in mind, but let's stop here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler version of your algorithm, using a simpler dictionary structure.

```
result = 0
cnt = {}
for elem in A:
    if elem not in cnt:
        cnt[elem] = 0
    cnt[elem] += 1

for k in range(len(A)):
    cnt[A[k]] -= 1  # uncount A[k]
    for j in range(k):
        for i in range(j):
            x = A[i] * A[j] * A[k]
            if x in cnt and cnt[x] > 0:
                result += cnt[x]
```

Notice that through the loop structure we ensure i < j < k and
that A[0,...,k] are always erased from the counts in the cnt dictionary. This runs in $O(n^3)$ (assuming $O(1)$ hashmap)